# Factory functions and composition

Tags: javascript, composition, function-composition, factory-method

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
const calculateDiameter = (circle) => ({
  get diameter() {
    return (circle.radius * 2);
  }
});

const calculateCircumference = (circle) => ({
  get circumference () {
    return (2 * (22 / 7) * circle.radius)
  }
});

const createCircle = (radius) => {
  const circle = {
    radius
  };
  
  return Object.assign(
    circle,
    calculateDiameter(circle),
    calculateCircumference(circle)
  )
}

// Create a cirlce
const myCircle = createCircle(2);
console.log( myCircle.diameter ) // returns: 4
console.log( myCircle.circumference ) // returns: 12.571428571428571
```

What I'd like to do is pass the output of `calculateDiameter()` to `calculateCircumference()`, so here is what I did:

```
// The following function was NOT modified
const calculateDiameter = (circle) => ({
  get diameter() {
    return (circle.radius * 2);
  }
});

const calculateCircumference2 = (circle) => ({
  get circumference () {
    return ((22 / 7) * circle.diameter)
  }
});

const createCircle2 = (radius) => {
  const circle = {
    radius
  };

  const circleWithDiameter = Object.assign(
    circle,
    calculateDiameter(circle),
  )
  
  return Object.assign(
    circleWithDiameter,
    calculateCircumference2(circleWithDiameter)
  )
}

// Create a cirlce
const myCircle2 = createCircle2(2);
console.log( myCircle2.diameter ) // returns: 4
console.log( myCircle2.circumference ) // returns: 12.571428571428571
```

Is this approach described in `createCircle2()` correct? In other words, should I create a middle step object (i.e., `circleWithDiameter`) to allow me to pass the diameter to `calculateCircumference2()`? It seems like an overload. Is there a more succinct way or direct way to call `calculateDiameter()` from within `calculateCircumference2()`?

The reason for this question is I will have a very complex object (as opposed to the circle), and those middle steps seem to be too convoluted.

Comment: “circumference”, and yes, this is too convoluted. Write a `getCircumference` function that takes a circle and returns a number. `Math.PI` exists, by the way.

Comment: You're mutating the original `{ radius }` object (which is what the `calculate...` functions' return values are closed over) with `Object.assign`, so you can use `circle.diameter` **in the first example**. But why not just write the class: https://tsplay.dev/mb3zbW

Comment: @Ry- Can you explain your solution in more details please? Not sure I follow. Thanks.

Comment: _"Write a `getCircumference` function that takes a circle and returns a number"_ -> e.g. `const getCircumference = ({ diameter }) => Math.PI * diameter;`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying to avoid classes in my solution in the first place. My classes are getting too large and complex, and I thought of trying composition, and hence the question.

Comment: But doesn't this show you that you aren't moving in the right direction? It's much more code than the class, and you still have to hold all of the state in your head (hence the confusion about whether/when `diameter` is accessible on `circle`).

Comment: I've already did that, instead of calling it `getCircumference`, i called it `calculateCircumference2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255335/discussion-between-greeso-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: "*My classes are getting too large and complex*" - can you show a better example of your problem? The `radius`, `diameter` and `circumference` *do* belong to a single `circle` object, there is no need to decompose them. Notice that some things are inherently complex, there is no reason to avoid a large class just for the sake of the line count. What exactly are you trying to gain from using composition?

Comment: Why are you using getters here? `const calculateDiameter = (circle) => ({ diameter: circle.radius * 2 });` is much simpler. And can more easily be changed to `const addDiameter = (circle) => ({ ...circle, diameter: circle.radius * 2 });` (or `circle => Object.assign(circle, {diameter: …})`), which is much more composable with other functions since the caller doesn't need to call `Object.assign` themselves

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your comment. Regarding to your request for a better example. Honestly the circle is the best way to describe it. I have complex objects, and those objects have properties, and methods that use those properties. My current solution is via classes, but I thought it is better to use composition because some methods should only be available in certain conditions. Best way to think of it is there are properties (e.g., radius) and intermediate methods that use those properties (diameter) and other methods that use those properteis and intermediate methods (circumference).

Comment: @Bergi I do not necessarily need to use getters. But since I am only retrieving values derived from other values, I resorted to getters.

Comment: @Greeso Can you expand on "some methods should only be available in certain conditions", please? That does not apply to a circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255351/discussion-between-greeso-and-bergi).

Comment: @Bergi - I think it is better to discuss this in the chat. i will log on to it